# BS4 Responsive Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a countdown timer embedded on my website, which functions well and uses the below html:

```
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/OJNzXEB

The issue arises however, on mobile, when I would like the 4 blocks to responsively form into a cube, correctly spaced. Stacked 2 by 2. It seems to move for the last most block, however I cannot seem to get this to work for the others, and remain spaced evenly. I am using Bootstrap 4.

CSS:

```
#clockdiv{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00BF96;
    display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
    padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00816A;
    display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
    padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: -10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your problem. https://codepen.io/Ultra_Hopeful/pen/bGpLeRK

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.days).slice(-2);
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date("sep 18, 2020 15:37:25")));


initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
#clockdiv{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:5px;
  width:fit-content;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
#clockdiv div{
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding:5px;
  background: #00BF96;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size:100%;
  background: #00816A;
}

.smalltext{
  padding: 4px 0px 5px 0px;
  font-size:16px;
}
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { #clockdiv { grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; } }

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { #clockdiv { grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; } }

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { #clockdiv { grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; } }

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section style="background-color: pink; color: white;">
  <div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <h1>BIRTHDAY COUNTDOWN</h1>
    <div id="clockdiv">

      <div>
        <span class="days"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
      </div> 

      <div>
        <span class="hours"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
      </div> 

      <div>
        <span class="minutes"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
      </div> 

      <div>
        <span class="seconds"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this causes a few issues- it changes the look of the blocks, removing the border. There is also no padding and the sizing is completely changed and no longer stay in their blocks when it goes into the four square mode. https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/abNqbGN

Comment: Hello Stevens I edited as you say and if you find your answer then don't forget upvote the answer.

Comment: This works regarding spacing, however, the timer itself looks very different to the original. The spacing is off- I am using Bootstrap, perhaps it would be possible using their grid system?